# git graph parent child tabular format

Tags: python, git, d3.js

I am working on git  and I am very much interested to see my changes into graph format . So I tried below command .

```
git log --oneline --graph --color --all --decorate
```

[image]

The above graph is not clear and tough to interpret .
Then i found another command , which has GUI. This was little more intuitive.

```
gitk --all
```

[image]

After doing some experiment , I thought of building  d3 graph for more clear view . Something Like below . For that i need below data in table format .

```
| Commmit ID | Branch | Parent Id |
-----------------------------------
| 123ghj     | Master | Null      |
-----------------------------------
| 123hj      | Master | 123ghj    |
-----------------------------------
| 3456jk     | Master |123ghj     |
```

By keeping commit parent child  , I can construct tree kind of structure.
Which I will use in d3.js to create graph like visualization . Can you help me to get this parent child structure using git command or group of command in python .
[image]

Comment: this might help: https://github.com/esc/git-big-picture

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should get you started. The "--pretty" format supplied is key:

```
git log --branches --tags --remotes --date-order --pretty="%H,%P,%D"
```

Notice how I'm using: `--pretty="%H,%P,%D"`.  (Note: you can use the lowercase %h and %p instead to see abbreviated commitId hashes).

%H expands to show the commitId.

%P expands to show the parent commitIds.

%D expands to show the decorations (tags and branches).

But there are a few subtle problems with it:

- %P will expand to all of %H's parent commits (separated by space), and so you'll need run the output through a 2nd script to better normalize that into a format suitable for D3.
- %P might expand to 3 or more commits (very rare).  These are called octopus merges!
- %D expands to a comma separated list of decorations (branch and tag labels), and there's no limit on how many branches and tags a single commit might have.

Sample output (scroll to the right to see the branches and tags!):

```
d5cf1a13b9a8dad3f18eefcc676399a5c1b805de,8026da6db0fd7dbfe9c9eac1d1567827dd047e84 741bfe3932de28c20f401cc7e0447fffb2bea7d6,HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD, HEAD
8026da6db0fd7dbfe9c9eac1d1567827dd047e84,624fe22914182b6ed05db3811d7c9fb9189273e6,
741bfe3932de28c20f401cc7e0447fffb2bea7d6,8b5d09a195f4d254d257d56fe7d10073fdf0cb23,origin/PHP-7.0, PHP-7.0
624fe22914182b6ed05db3811d7c9fb9189273e6,c1868b00cdeb7880a8372727da66aa30d94dc765 8b5d09a195f4d254d257d56fe7d10073fdf0cb23,
8b5d09a195f4d254d257d56fe7d10073fdf0cb23,99c44458da7f60af017f233a1e9d0b3f54efcdb4 8cd903ea685a6ef56aa77e95c00db8aac53a7c39,
8cd903ea685a6ef56aa77e95c00db8aac53a7c39,67f0770036f866f6f0dadc044cdc8f94a5b9f030,origin/PHP-5.6, PHP-5.6
99c44458da7f60af017f233a1e9d0b3f54efcdb4,f8506c062f8c4f72e12f20487bbb8c453602e5e7 4d4c6cf14ee855039f6dafcdcd14c32124963461,
c1868b00cdeb7880a8372727da66aa30d94dc765,ff8337b783dc8d5f44608afc87f51998f3223859 22475055c658e0efded795e8dea543406e6842a6,
```